# Can't Run PHP artisan commands

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run Front-end project built in Laravel blade PHP locally.
i did the following commands:
1- Composer install --ignore-platform-reqs.
2- Composer update --ignore-platform-reqs.
during the process i get the error in image attached
and what ever PHP artisan command i try to run like PHP artisan serve or PHP artisan package:discover
i get this error in the image attached.
What should i do?.
Note: I did install PHP v8.1.2 and Composer.

[fatal error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxT45.png)

Comment: which version of laravel do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is a version mismatch. Use PHP 7.x instead.